# phpstorm: change colour of current search match

Tags: ide, themes, phpstorm

I want to change the colour of the current match when searching, as the scheme I'm using (Heat of the Night) doesn't stand out very well (black on grey).

In `Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General` modifying "Text search result" works ok (which is all the matches except the first one), but "Search result" and "Search result (write access)" only effect the preview and not the actual editor window.

Is there some other setting I need to update?

Comment: To make life a bit easier: please add a screenshot that illustrates the situation stating what place/color you want to change (preferably using default color scheme)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just worked it out - the editor selects each match as you iterate through them, so what I needed to change was "Selection background" and "Selection foreground".